# Woocommerce agroup and sort only uniques file_name and dont repeat them

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have jumped into this @7uc1f3r code who helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60752984/12500693

but this is giving me a problem:

```
|   PRODUCT    |  FILENAME /LINK/   |
|   prdct1     |  filenamex 1       | 
|   ''         |  filenamex 3       |
|   ''         |  filenamex 4       |
|   ''         |  filenamex 2       | 
|   prdct2     |  filenamez 2       |
|   ''         |  filenamez 1       |
|   ''         |  filenamez 1       |
|   ''         |  filenamez 2       |
|   prdct3     |  filenamey 1       |
```

giving me both unordered and duplicate (because the download hash its difference (one from purshace another from subscription), in this scenario page i dont care if hide one our another.

this is what i need:

```
|   PRODUCT    |  FILENAME /LINK/   |
|   prdct1     |  filenamex 1       |   /* order the filenames */
|   ''         |  filenamex 2       |
|   ''         |  filenamex 3       |
|   ''         |  filenamex 4       | 
|   prdct2     |  filenamez 1       |
|   ''         |  filenamez 2       |   /*dont repeat filename based on the order key/id 
|   prdct3     |  filenamey 1       |
```

Comment: Okay, what have you tried so far to adapt my original code to your needs?

Comment: @7uc1f3r i stoped with this scenario, with unorder files from product and repeating 2x files if i already have a product linked to a subscription too (generating 2 diferents keys, but actually i need to show only 1 of the same file name)